# DatePickerAndroid "spinner" mode opens both "spinner" and "calendar" in Tablet

Tags: android, react-native, android-datepicker

When i open DatePickerAndroid with mode "spinner" in API 23 phone (android 6.0) it opens correctly(also tested on android 8).
But if i change to a tablet (Nexus 9 2048x1563 xhdpi) with API 23 (android 6.0 x86), then both spinner and calendar open as you can see in screenshot: (Also tested on Android 8 and android 7.1 tablet and bug exists, tested with RN v0.56 and RN v0.57)
[image: screenshot].

The code used:

```
DatePickerAndroid.open({
    date: new Date(),
    mode: "spinner"
});
```

Also opened as issue in [react-native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21313).
Has anyone found any workaround?

Comment: what's the problem? The real estate is more in tablet and view is using that to give the user option to choose any.

Comment: This is not the behavior if mode "calendar"is chosen though, so seems more like a bug. Or at least i should be able to alter this "feature".